# Why does jquery run incrementally with every click?

Tags: html, jquery

There is a simple function written in jquery. I print the incoming data con left with each click. But every time I click, the previous id data is also written to the console.

```
data_id: 38
-------------------
data_id: 38
data_id: 45
-------------------
data_id: 38
data_id: 38
data_id: 45
data_id: 38
data_id: 38
data_id: 45
data_id: 45
data_id: 56
```

As above.

```
    $('body').on('click', 'input.data_update', function (e){
        
        var data_id  = $("input[name='data_id']").val();
        
        function update(data_id){
            console.log("data_id: " + data_id);
        }
        
        $(document).on("click", "input.form_button_1", function (e){
            update(data_id);
        });
        
        var single_click = true;
        $(document).on("keydown", function (e){
            if (!single_click) return;
            var key = e.which;
            if(key == 13 || key == 27){
                update(data_id);
            single_click = false;
            }
            
        });
        
    });
```

When I use .off () to prevent this, I can't print any data

```
        $(document).off().on("click", "input.form_button_1", function (e){
            update(data_id);
        });
        
        $(document).off().on("keydown", function (e){
            var key = e.which;
            if(key == 13 || key == 27){
                update(data_id);
            }
        });
```

It works fine when I use window instead of var. But how can I solve it without using window?

```
var data_id  = $("input[name='data_id']").val();
window.data_id  = $("input[name='data_id']").val();
```

Comment: You're binding events inside event binds. Seems logical to me you're incrementing the click events. You can get away with this when using `one()`. A better approach would be to pass data from the elements => `data_id` should be fetched inside `input.form_button_1` click event AND put event binds alongside eachother, don't embed them.

Answer (score 0):

All your workarounds aside let's try to refactor your main functionality first by binding events separately:

```
/* 1. action to take after events are triggered */
function updateId(id){
    console.log('update id: ' + id);
}

function updateEl(el){
    console.log('update el: ' + el.value);
    // do something with this element
    // just trivial functionality below
    $(el).data('clicked', true);
    $(el).attr('data-clicked', true);
    $(el).addClass('disabled');
}

/* 2. defining events */
$(document.body).on('click', 'input.data_update:not(.disabled)', function (e){
    var data_id  = $('input[name="data_id"]').val(); // unique element? relative to clicked element?

    updateId(data_id);
    updateEl(e.currentTarget);
});

$(document.body).on('click', 'input.form_button_1', function (e){
    updateEl(e.currentTarget);
});
    
$(document.body).on('keydown', 'input.data_update:not(.disabled)', function (e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (key === 13 || key === 27){
        updateEl(e.currentTarget);
    }        
});
```

So not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `updateId` or how your HTML is layed out. It helps if you post this as well.

If for example you want to update only once ... you can select only elements that are not disabled.